# Select between the 8th of this month and the 8th of last month, for every month

Tags: php, mysql

How would you select all records between the 8th of this month and the 8th of last month without passing in the current month? My date column is date type.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '8th of last month' AND 
                   '8th of this month'
```

I've tried working out the date calculations in PHP then sending them to MySQL. But it gets a bit complicated when factoring in years. I'm wondering if this could be accomplished with SQL instead?

Comment: I like to keep this all in the db so would use YEAR(NOW())-MONTH(NOW())-8 AND YEAR(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)-MONTH(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP might be more *straightforward* from a readability standpoint using [relative time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) with [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime).

The following should get you started:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('eighth of last month'));
```

#### UPDATE

*Ordinals* don't work as I thought above. However, *assuming* you use the same day of the month (i.e 8th). The following is fine:

```
echo date('Y-m-08', strtotime('last month'));
```

Comment: unfortently that does not work. The closest you can get using strtotime is echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days', strtotime('first day of last month')));

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution

```
echo date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n') - 1, 8));
```

If you want to use strtotime

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days', strtotime('first day of last month')));
```